Rewrite URL for PHP Containing Space and Dash
I need to update my website to have SEO friendly URLs. The website uses PHP and a MySQL database. The page in question takes a GET variable called cat (short for category) from the URL.
Here are a few examples of categories I need to work with. They can contain multiple spaces and dashes.
Hex Bolt
U-Bolt <- this category has a dash already
Tension Control Bolt
The current URL looks like this
example.com/catalog/parts/index.php?cat=Hex+Bolt
Ultimately I would like the URLs to look like the following:
example.com/catalog/parts/hex-bolt
example.com/catalog/parts/u-bolt <- leave the dash
example.com/catalog/parts/tension-control-bolt
I believe this involves an htaccess rule. How would you go about pulling this off where you could replace the dash back to a space vs keep the dash if it was initially a dash? If you could include the HTACCESS rule and any other handling needed on the PHP script(s).

This is an impossible task. Simply because the information to decide, whether there should be a blank, a dash or whatever is not present in the requested URL. A rewriting rule cannot somehow make up that information by magic. It can only react to the information actually available.

Looks like you need to alter your application logic then such that it is able to handle that parameter regardless of how the words are connected.

You should update the categories you have in your database, to a common format. Since you probably don't want to change how you display the category names on your site, introduce an extra "slug" field in the database, and write the common format you want to use in your URLs, into there - and then use that field to find the record matching the passed URL parameter. Then all you still need is the URL rewriting from /catalog/parts/... to /catalog/parts/index.php?cat=....

Thanks for the input. Ran with the idea of adding a url or "slug" field to our database to accomplish this like CBroe suggested. That seems to be working well. Thanks!
